# Log contents of text file before deleting

Tags: batch-file

My script isn't logging the contents of `run.txt` to `log.txt`

I've tried to remove the delete command to see if it was deleting it too quickly and therefore couldn't log. But that wasn't the case.
What should I change?

```
@ECHO OFF &setlocal

SET File=run.txt

type %File%
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (%File%) do (echo >> log.txt)
del "%File%" /s /f /q > nul

pause
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you actually `echo` *something* to the logfile, you might meet with more success. Perhaps something radical like `(echo %%A>> log.txt)`

Comment: How did you run the script?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple way to do the task you are requiring.

```
@echo off
REM Will only grab the first line of the file
set /p file=<run.txt

REM For the last line use a for loop
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%file%) do set last_line=%%a

(
echo %file%
)>>log.txt
del /f %file% >nul
If not %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    ECHO ERROR - %errorlevel%
    pause
    exit /b 
)
ECHO Success!
timeout /t 003
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

**EXPLANATION**

`set /p` is for set prompt.  For more information you can use `set /?` in your CMD window or check out [this site](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html).

I wish I could speak more on what `<` does, but what it is doing here is piping the content of run.txt to our variable.

Then we echo out our variable to our log file with `(ECHO This is our %file%)>>destination`

`>>` is to append where `>` is to overwrite the file.

```
(
echo %file%
echo.
)>>%file%
```

Checking for an error is probably unnecessary, but I believe it is a good habit to build on which is what I am trying to do with that `If not %errorlevel%` statement.

No error?  We Success and timeout ourselves for xxx seconds.

Comment: Indeed added the %s I left out

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@ECHO OFF &setlocal

SET "File=run.txt"

type "%File%" >> "log.txt" && (del "%File%" /f > nul)

pause
```

Comment: There is definitely, in this case, no need for the `/s` or `/q` options with your `del` command. In order for `type` to work, `"%File%"` must be in the current working directory, so using `/s` could effectively delete a file with the same name elsewhere in the tree, which hasn't just been replicated. `/q` is use if deleting a targets using a wildcard, and you're not using a wildcard, you're using a full and complete file name. You should also, for robustness, use the recommended syntax when defining your variable, i.e. `SET "File=run.txt", _the doublequotes protect you from poison characters_.

Comment: @Compo thanks for your comment, you're totally right. Simply I did not pay attention to exact commands' syntax except for the task asked. I know `set "variable=no matter what"` is the most correct syntax, a bit less about `del` command options. I just wanted to give the user a prompt for solving his required task. Hope this is helpful for him (as well as for me).